# API requests always return 404 no matter what

Tags: python, api, http-status-code-404, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to automate the trading strategy that I executed manually before. This requires communicating with my broker through an API. I am authorizing through HTTP basic auth. To test I tried to make an API request to get information about funds in my account.

At first, I was getting `401` responses and it turned out that I was using the wrong identification information.

After I fixed this issue, all API requests that I am making are giving me `404` responses.

An example

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

response = requests.get("https://api-demo.exante.eu/md/{version}/accounts", auth=HTTPBasicAuth
    ('name', 'pass'))

print(response)
```

After this, I tried some code online to check whether or not there are other problems. I tried this

https://gist.github.com/rshrc/127ba2c20df74263d71bc5a5595c8969

and this also gives me `404`.

Link to my brokers API documentation:

https://api-live.exante.eu/api-docs/#section/API-versions

Does anyone know where might be the problem? Directions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Have you replaced `{version}` with the appropriate value. Should be "2.0" or "3.0".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not passing a version with the `{version}` variable. Don't forget to also format the URL string with an `f` before it. This should work:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

version = "3.0"
response = requests.get(f"https://api-demo.exante.eu/md/{version}/accounts", auth=HTTPBasicAuth
    ('name', 'pass'))

print(response)
```